# Merge [todo] and [todos]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I found those 2 tags about TODO comments in the code, here are some stats:

- [todo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todo) - 117 questions
- [todos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todos) - 47 questions

They have similar excerpt and serve one purpose. I suggest to merge them or create a synonym.

Comment: I guess the followup question here is which is the main tag and which is the synonym

Comment: I beleive, th `todo` should be main and `todos` should be marked as synonym as it just implies multiples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked through all of the questions individually, and clearly they are all about exactly the same thing. There is no reason why we need two different tags for this, so I've merged them.

The only reason that [todos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todos) exists is because it got created first (8 years, 11 months ago, as opposed to 7 years, 9 months ago). We don't allow pluralized forms of existing tags to be created, so this one isn't going to be coming back. I've naturally chosen [todo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todo) as the form to retain, because (A) we prefer non-plural forms unless there are extenuating circumstances, and (B) this is much more readable and obvious in my opinion.

Fun fact: a synonym mapping [todo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todo) to [todos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todos) was proposed by [Dima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13313/dima) way back in November of 2010. It languished without any votes since then, because the tag synonym system is broken and largely unknown.

The [todo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todo) tag probably would still benefit from some clean-up, but doing this merge does not make that any more difficult.

Comment: I've removed this tag from on-topic questions where it was unrelated. Now there should be only related questions and a portion of off-topic questions that should be closed.